# Increasing the index of the ListView Builder by two in Flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to place two list tiles in a single row. How can I increase the increment of the index in Flutter by two in each iteration?

[image]

In the below code, as you can see, I am trying to use two lists in a row, and then I want the index to be `index+2`. But, by default, the index is increased by `index+1`.

**How do I increment it by two?**

```
body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: song.length - 1,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
      return Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(song[index]),
              subtitle: Text(singer[index]),
              trailing: Text(time[index]),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Player(
                      song[index],
                      singer[index],
                      time[index],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(song[index+1]),
              subtitle: Text(singer[index+1]),
              trailing: Text(time[index+1]),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Player(
                      song[index+1],
                      singer[index+1],
                      time[index+1],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  ),
```

Comment: You can try gridview. Which is more better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always good to use GridView when you want two item in a row, but if you want to use list view the following code will help you.

You can maintain index by other manual index.

```
List<int> list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  int extraindex = -2;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount:
              list.length % 2 == 0 ? list.length / 2 : list.length ~/ 2 + 1,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            extraindex += 2;
            return Row(
              children: [
                Text(list[extraindex].toString()),
                if (extraindex + 1 < list.length)
                  Text(list[extraindex + 1].toString()),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: "Thank you both the method work i used grid view " for anyone who wants to refer grid view https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/grid-lists

Answer (score 2):

```
List<int> list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount:
          list.length % 2 == 0 ? list.length ~/ 2 : list.length ~/ 2 + 1,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
        return Row(
          children: [
            Text(list[index * 2].toString()),
            if (index * 2 +1+ 1 < list.length)
              Text(list[index * 2 + 1].toString()),
          ],
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: while your code can answer the question, it is a good practice to advocate your solution

Answer (score 1):

yes You can maintain index by other manual index but you need to keep the relation between the new index and the listview index to not have trouble when listview index is decrementing.
here is my code:

```
 ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0, top: 10),
        physics: disableScroll
            ? NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
            : ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: getCountClassic(),
        itemBuilder: (context2, j) {
          int a = j + 2;

          if (j == 0) {
            a = 0;
          }
          if (j == 1) {
            a = 2;
          }
          int b = a + 1;
          log("j=$j , a= $a , b=$b");

          return j % 2 == 0 || j == 1
              ? Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: context.isDarkMode ? null : ColorConstants.white,
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 12.0, vertical: 6),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: ClassicItemGrid2(
                          item: items[a],
                        ),
                      ),
                      (b < items.length)
                          ? Expanded(
                              child: ClassicItemGrid2(
                              item: items[(b)],
                            ))
                          : Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              : SizedBox();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to tackle this requirement - I used a separate counter, and incremented by two on every iteration. `itemCount` was given half of actual count, itemcount-1 if length is an odd number. below is the code -

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final doctor = //yourlist;
    int icount = 0;
    var length = doctor.specialization.length / 2;
    var listLength = length.floor();

ListView.builder(
                itemCount: listLength,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                  if (i != 0) {
                    icount = icount + 2;
                  }
                  return Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        RoundedText(displayText: doctor.specialization[icount]),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                        RoundedText(
                            displayText: doctor.specialization[icount + 1])
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),  
}
```